# htaccess redirect query string and discard

Tags: .htaccess

Having trouble with redirecting a dynamic URL. This is what I want to accomplish:

```
Redirect 301 /content/index.php?id=423 http://www.domain.com/new-page/
```

I tried this

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(([^&]*&)*)id=423$
RewriteRule ^content/index\.php$ http://www.domain.com/new-page [L,R=301]
```

but had no luck. Thank you!
ps/
I lost some para
work with this code

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/([A-Za-z]*)-([^.]+)-([0-9]+).html$ $1/$4-$2-$3.html [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the query in the replacement URL. Otherwise the original query is taken:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=423$
RewriteRule ^content/index\.php$ http://example.com/new-page? [L,R=301]
```

And if you want to preserve other URL arguments, try this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(([^&]*&)*)id=423&*([^&].*)?$
RewriteRule ^content/index\.php$ http://example.com/new-page?%1%3 [L,R=301]
```